# Conditional expectation of this stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingale

I'm just beginning to learn about stochastic processes and encountered this very elementary problem that confused me a bit:

We toss a coin that lands on Head with probability $p$ and Tail with $q=1-p$. This probability never changes. We define $W_n$ to be $-1$ when the $n$-th toss is Tail and $1$ if Head. The problem was to determine whether or not $(W_n)_n$ is a martingale. While solving, the lecturer writes this: $$\mathbb{E}(W_{n+1}\vert\mathcal{F}_n)=\mathbb{E}(W_{n+1})=p-q$$
Here $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(W_1,\dots,W_n)$. He argues that since the $n$-th toss and the $n+1$-th toss are independent, $W_{n+1}$ and $\mathcal{F}_n$ are independent, which is why the above holds. I get this.

But I also think that $W_n$'s are defined on the space $(\{H,T\},\{\emptyset,\{H\},\{T\},\{H,T\}\},\mathbb{P})$ where $\mathbb{P}(H)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(T)=q$. So $\sigma(W_1,\dots,W_n)$ is the entire $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset,\{H\},\{T\},\{H,T\}\}$. But then $$\mathbb{E}(W_{n+1}\vert\mathcal{F}_n)=W_{n+1}$$
Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong? This will really help me learn about the topic.

Comment: The entire martingale is defined on the space of all *countable sequences* of possible outcomes.  You cannot make sense of, say, $\mathcal{F}_2$ otherwise.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the response. I am not sure I understand what you mean. For instance, I think the conclusion to the problem is that $(W_n)$ is NOT a martingale.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "stochastic process" rather than "martingale."  What I am inviting you to consider is how you could possibly even define both $W_1$ and $W_2$ on the tiny space you have described in a way that makes them independent.

Comment: @whuber I get what you mean- the outcomes should be of the form $$(H,H,T,T,H,T,\dots)$$. But the individual random variables are defined on the tiny spaces are they not?

Comment: @whuber Ok, I think I see what you mean. $W_n$ just tells you what the $n$-th entry in the particular outcome is. So the experiment is tossing a coin countably many times and the sample space is all possible sequences. The sigma-algebra would be the power set I assume.

Comment: The space can be some general, abstract one.  But a standard model--the smallest possible--is the set $\Omega=\{(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots)\mid \omega_i \in \{H,T\}\}.$ The problem is that if you have one copy of your "tiny space" and a separate, distinct copy, you still haven't any way to compare a random variable defined on one with a random variable defined on the other.  You need a space on which all the random variables are simultaneously defined.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/123754/919 for details of how this is done for just $W_1$ and $W_2$ alone.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. If you can spare a few more minutes: Is there a natural way to define a probability measure on this $\Omega$? For finite tosses I see that the space is basically the product probability space and naturally $P(\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n)=P(\omega_1)\dots P(\omega_n)$. What happens when the sequences are infinite?

Comment: You define the probability measure on a basis of the measurable sets.  That basis naturally corresponds to all *finite prefixes* of sequences.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164995/919 for the details.